# TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null while using angular-datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I am trying to use `angular-datatables` and getting the error below:

```
 - TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null while using angular-datatables".
   Note: all index files and dependencies have been included.
```

view.html

```
<table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="row-border hover">
</table>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.finalArray = [];
$scope.dtOptions;
$scope.dtColumns;
/*code includes a function call to url to fetch data
after it is successful, it goes to function dt */

 function dt(){
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function(){return $q.when($scope.finalArray);})
    .withTableTools("bower_components/datatables-tabletools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf")
    .withTableToolsButtons([
        'copy',
        'print', {
            'sExtends': 'collection',
            'sButtonText': 'Save',
            'aButtons': ['csv', 'xls', 'pdf']
        }
    ]);
 $scope.dtColumns = [];
    for(var i in $scope.columnTable){    $scope.dtColumns.push(DTColumnBuilder.newColumn($scope.columnTable[i]).withTitle($scope.columnTable[i]));
}
  }
```

This is the error message that I am getting
error message :

```
at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:131)
at Object.t.iterator (jquery.dataTables.min.js:96)
at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:131)
at Object.t.extend.g [as destroy] (jquery.dataTables.min.js:99)
at m.fnDestroy (jquery.dataTables.min.js:80)
at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:84)
at Function.n.extend.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.n.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at m [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.min.js:83)
at h.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.min.js:159)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What version of angular-datatables and angular are you using?

Comment: Did you try that [link](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/150)?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the comment of Mr.MaicolBen [here](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/150#issuecomment-66795293). It may help.

"The table haven't plugins, it seems to me that the table is not ready when the directive is applied. Because when I create other directive that apply the plugin after a second work! But the behavior is slow:"

```
.directive('myDatatable', function($compile, $timeout){
    return function(scope, elem, attr) {
        $timeout(function(){
            elem.attr('datatable', 'ng');
            elem.removeAttr('my-datatable');
            $compile(elem)(scope);
        }, 1000);
  };
})
```